# How to set the default java in Solaris?

Tags: java

I just installed the latest java in `/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_30`

Now how do I make this java is the default java for the entire OS? As of now it is still using java 1.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it...

```
$which java
/usr/bin/java
$ls -ld /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root other 16 Apr 8 12:41 /usr/bin/java -> ../java/bin/java
$rm /usr/bin/java
$ln -s /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java /usr/bin/java
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that just changing the symlink `/usr/bin/java` is insufficient, because there's more than one Java symlink in /usr/bin:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/java*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         16 May 21  2015 /usr/bin/java -> ../java/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         17 May 21  2015 /usr/bin/javac -> ../java/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         19 May 21  2015 /usr/bin/javadoc -> ../java/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         17 May 21  2015 /usr/bin/javah -> ../java/bin/javah
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         17 May 21  2015 /usr/bin/javap -> ../java/bin/javap
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         18 Jul 21  2015 /usr/bin/javaws -> ../java/bin/javaws
```

Instead, I would take advantage of the fact that `/usr/java` is itself a symlink and replace it instead of 6+ others.  Here is how I made JDK 8 the default:

```
# cd /usr
# rm java
# ln -s jdk/jdk1.8.0_121 java
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
```